# Engadget Like most commented plugins

Tags: plugins, comments

i am looking for a most commented plugin like that of in [engadget](http://www.engadget.com/) website and [propakistani](http://propakistani.pk). I would be very thankful if someone could help me out with it. 
Thanks
[image]

Comment: http://codecanyon.net/item/popular-posts-bar-widget/115225

Comment: You can get it free from [here]( Get Engadget Like Most Commented WordPress Plugin For Free:http://www.startupsandfinance.com/engadget-like-most-commented-plugin-get-engadget-like-most-commented-wordpress-plugin-for-free/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a plugin like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/ to get a widget based on popular posts (I've never personally used that one) or write your own. Everything else is just HTML markup and CSS.

Comment: Thanks. I had purchased the plugin mentioned by ijaas before your answer, so I have already invested 10$ for a product. Still, your answer is better so it should be marked as selected.